# Unable to use SSL Proxy in Charles 4.1.4 on a device with iOS 11.0.1

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy

I have used Charles before and it has worked. I'm not sure if it's an issue with ***Charles 4.1.4***, ***macOS High Sierra 10.13***, or ***iOS 11.0.1***

Both my Mac and iPhone are on the same network. The proxy has been configured on the iPhone, it just can't get a connection out.

I can't visit any sites including [www.charlesproxy.com/getssl](http://www.charlesproxy.com/getssl)

I have gone to *Device Settings -> General -> About -> Certificate Trust Settings* 
But *Turn on Charles Proxy Custom Root Certificate* is not there.

Has anyone else encountered this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading Charles to the newest version (4.2.1) fixed the issue for me - the `/getssl` site does work.